# Why isn't the webpage loding while scraping linkedin?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, proxy

> In this code I am trying to scrape a Linkedin profile using Selenium
> but the driver is not able to load the page I guess IP has been
> blocked and I am new to the concept of proxy rotating or any concept
> that is used in such cases. It would be a great help if you could help
> me understand how this is done.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\chromedriver.exe')


def linkedin_login():
    global driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeswitches', ['enable-automation'])
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    try:
        driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')

        username = 'username'
        password = 'password'
    
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn__primary--large from__button--floating').click()
        time.sleep(8)
    except ImportError:
        print('Closing')

def search_profiles():
   search_profile = input('What profile do you want to search?')
   search_profile = search_profile.split()
   search = search_profile[0] + "%20" + search_profile[1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Sign In" button's class name is incorrect, specifically is missing a dot(.)

Instead of:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn__primary--large from__button--floating').click()
```

Use:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn__primary--large.from__button--floating').click()
```

That will click the button.

Also, if you run the code you shared, you are calling the webdriver but not calling your function.

I tested the below code and worked fine (remember to update your path and LinkedIn credentials):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/armentaahumada/Downloads/chromedriver')


def linkedin_login():
    global driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeswitches', ['enable-automation'])
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    try:
        driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')

        username = 'username'
        password = 'password'
    
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn__primary--large.from__button--floating').click()
        time.sleep(8)
    except ImportError:
        print('Closing')

def search_profiles():
   search_profile = input('What profile do you want to search?')
   search_profile = search_profile.split()
   search = search_profile[0] + "%20" + search_profile[1]

linkedin_login()
```